# Trying to retain selected checkbox/radio buttons value if previously selected

Tags: html, visual-studio, razor, html-select

```
@Request.Form["Gender"] == "Male" ? "selected" : ""
```

Keeps saying I'm missing name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the value of radiobutton to your database. Then create conditional. If radiobutton just 2 options, use `if conditional` to keep selected radiobutton. And if more than 2 options you can use `switch conditional`.

This is sample of radiobutton:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male" /> Male</div>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female" /> Female</div>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="other" value="Other" /> Other</div>
```

The script to keep selected radiobutton:

```
<script>
    var gender = "@Model.Gender";
    switch (theme) {
        case "Male":
            document.getElementById("male").checked = true;;
            break;
    case "Female":
            document.getElementById("female").checked = true;;
            break;
    case "Other":
            document.getElementById("other").checked = true;;
            break;
    }
</script>
```

`"Model.Gender"` is the way used to call the value stored in the database.